# Using seq to print even numbered rows of text in R

Tags: r, seq

I'm currently having trouble in using the seq() function to print even number rows of text.
[image: example]

So as shown in the image above, say I want to print only rows 2 and 4. I have tried using the seq(by=2) function, however I'm only getting integers as my result. How should I approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this raw text or is it part of a data frame?

Comment: You have a data frame. You use `[` to subset a data frame. Like `df[c(1, 2, 3), ]` is the first 3 rows. `df[c(1, 10, 100), ]` is rows 1, 10, and 100. `df[seq(1, 101, by = 10), ]` would be rows 1, 11, 21, 31, .... Have I said enough?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is part of a data frame!

Comment: @GregorThomas Hello, thank you very much for your input! I get it now. I was previously doing something like df2 <- df(seq), which explains my error. Edit follow up: why is it necessary to add the ", " at the end of the seq()?

Comment: Data frames are subset as `data[rows, columns]`. You need to comma to indicate that you are subsetting rows, leaving it blank after to comma will default to all columns. But you could also do `df[1:3, 4:5]` to see the first 3 rows of the 4th and 5th columns. (If you leave out the comma, the assumption will be that you want to subset columns, not rows, due to data frame's being implemented as lists of columns.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Ah gotcha. Thanks again for your help!!